# Google APIs and Calendar, login token

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I would like to connect with my Google calendar.
I don't know how to use OAuth 2.0.
My parameters Google APIs:
`Client ID:`
`673534379963-342423423432vs315g.apps.googleusercontent.com`

`Client secret:`
`iu6V2J-42343242342XecmDounO`

`Redirect URIs:`
`urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

I get calendar:
`EventQuery myQuery = new EventQuery("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/MAIL/private/full");`
`Google.GData.Calendar.EventFeed oEventFeed = service.Query(myQuery);`

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I strongly recommend against publishing client ID and secret!